# How to let new and old subscribers sign up to a Mailchimp segment

Tags: mailchimp

I have a landing page with a Mailchimp form. I need visitors, including already signed up users, to be able to sign up to this Mailchimp form linked to the same audience list, but onto a segment. The end goal is to have a segment that also includes emails signed up to the main list, in order to target emails interested only to the product on that landing page.

The issue is that I cannot have a user already signed up to the main list, sign up to the landing page form segment. I cannot find any resource online on how to have a separate form on a landing page that allows any email to be added to the segment. Is the approach incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

If if you have made the "Group" visible, then existing users can "Update their preference" from any of your past emails. This option is usually located in the footer (that is added by MailChimp by default) of the email. Once the user follows the update process, they should be able to subscribe/unsubscribe from the groups as they please.

By the way, this is more of a question for the MailChimp Help Desk not for this forum.